# TeeChart- Candle Stick is not getting drawn correctly on Chart (.Net Version)

Tags: c#, .net, teechart

Currently I am facing very basic yet strange issue in TeeChart. Candle Charts are not getting drawn correctly as shown in following screenshot:
[Candle Stick Drawing Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RDlZ3.png)

The major problem with the candle sticks drawn is for some width size High and Low values are not aligned to the centre of the box. The same issue has been found in demo version of TeeChart. Find the attached screenshot here:[TeeChart Feature Demo with Candle Stick Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NW7XM.png)

Comment: Hello Sachin, 
I'm afraid I can't reproduce the problem using latest TeeChart 2017 4.1.2017.03140. Could you tell us which TeeChart For .Net version are you using? Thanks in advance

Comment: I am using TeeChart .Net version Build 4.1.2015.12160.

Answer (score 0):

Many thanks for the information. I confirm you the problem is fixed and the Candle Series works fine in latest TeeChart 2017 4.1.2017.03140.

I would like suggest you download our TeeChart 2017 4.1.2017.03140 evaluation version from [here](https://www.steema.com/downloads/net) and check if the latest version works as you expected.